# Cognos 11 How to Stop AutoSubmit Radio Button from running report

Tags: radio-button, show-hide, prompt, cognos

I have an HTML report that has the prompts right on the report page.  There are several prompts on this page.  One of the prompts is a static radio button prompt that is used for 3 hidden conditional date prompts (using a render variable).  In order for the radio button to work, it is set to auto submit.  The default is set to the first date prompt.  Every time the user selects the second or third option radio button, the report automatically runs.  Is there a way to stop the report from running every time the radio button is selected and just have the corresponding date prompt display?  No other prompts are auto submit.  Once all the prompts are set, the user submits the report. User can then change prompts as needed.  I just don't want the report to run every time that one radio button is selected.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Imagine you were asked this question.  What other information would you require to be able to answer?  Maybe things like Cognos version, which viewer is being used, etc....  Also, providing a simple report spec that demonstrates the problem using the samples data would enable someone to reproduce the problem and consider possible solutions.

Comment: It sounds like all of the prompts should be set before the report runs.  Would you be okay with having a prompt page?